# cd Program Files - the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: command-prompt

Genuinely can't understand this.

Very simply, when I type "cd Program Files" into the Command Prompt, I get the above error message.

I have a file which is "C:\Program Files", so can't understand what this is about.

I have also tried "cd 'Program Files'", which also doesn't work.

Comment: @Progman I tried that.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command line content, include the commands you are executing and the output/error messages you get. Also include the result of the command `dir` to your question.

Comment: @Progman `cd` is a special command and accepts spaces without quotes. From `cd /?`: *CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to
CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes.  For example: `cd \winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu` is the same as: `cd "\winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu"`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select proper disk:

```
D:\> C:
```

Then, try running:

```
C:\> cd %ProgramFiles%
```

Comment: What is the significance of referencing the D drive first?  I try that and it tells me access is denied

Comment: Well, the snipnet was supposed to show how the entire prompt looks from my perspective. What you should try then is - `C:`(To make sure you are on proper drive), and `cd %ProgramFiles%` - to switch to Program Files.